# Get access to generated class names in e.g. custom panel header renderer

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I'm using a Panel component from Office UI Fabric (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/panel). A panel is separated into header, content and footer, where the content is always scrollable in case there are too many lines to fit in. What I want to do is, add some other components into the header to make it sticky within the panel (in this case a Pivot, rendering some Tabs).

This is possible in general by using the `onRenderHeader` callback property of the Panel. When using this, I have to rerender the complete header with classes to get the same look and feel, but additionally inject my own components. The problem is, I cannot simply set `ms-Panel-header header` as `className` property, since at least `header` doesn't exist as class selector, but only as scoped version with a generated id-suffix (e.g. `header-103`) that can change when the DOM structure changes. Hence, I need to get access to these generated classes.

The only thing I could come up with, was storing a reference to the Panel component instance and using the internal `_classNames` property when rendering my custom header.
Here is an excerpt (using TypeScript):

```
private handleRenderHeader(): JSX.Element {
    const classNames = (this.panel.current as any)._classNames;
    return (
      <div className={classNames.header}>
        <p className={classNames.headerText} role="heading">
          My Headline
        </p>
        <Pivot
          selectedKey={this.selectedEntriesCategory}
          onLinkClick={this.handleSelectedEntriesCategoryClicked}
          headersOnly={true}
        >
          <PivotItem linkText="First Tab" itemIcon="Contact" />
          <PivotItem linkText="Second Tab" itemIcon="Group" />
        </Pivot>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is this the only solution to this problem or is there some "official" way to achieve this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`onRenderHeader` callback prop is passing back 3 arguments. The second one is the `defaultRenderer` you can use along with the first one. Here is a codepen that roughly shows how to do it without needing to care about the classNames coming by default: https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/oJMgzB

Comment: You would probably also need to adjust the position of the Pivots to align with the title.

Comment: Thanks, that comes very close to what I'm searching. However, I'd like to use the same positioning for the Pivots that is used for the header without copying its padding values manually. That's why I tried to put it inside the same div using the exact same header class. Would be great, if the `onRenderHeader` callback would receive the classes mapping as additional argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but if you must have the className you can run the default renderer and then access its props and then get the className property from that. I agree that it should be easier to accomplish what you're trying to!

Something like this:

```
    const element = defaultRenderer ? defaultRenderer(props) : null;
    const className = element ? element.props.className : '';
```